# Laravel Mail::send returns zero with no specific error in Mail::failures()

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am using `smtp` driver and this is my code to send email in laravel 5.2:

```
public function Sendmail()
{
    $data["mail_message"] = "Hello!";
    if(Mail::send('Emails.email', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from('webmaster@example.com', Input::get('name'));

        $message->to('amirhasan.hesam@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    }))
    {
        return "success";
    }
    else
    {
        return Mail::failures();
    }
}
```

the `Mail::failures()` returns `["amirhasan.hesam@gmail.com"]` with no specific error!

and this is my config on mail.php :

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '*******'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => "****@*****", 'name' => "Diling"],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),
'username' => env('*****@*****'),
'password' => env('*************************'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,

];
```

and I am using xamp right now to test the email. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you get in your log file? They are in this directory /project/storage/logs/

Comment: Even I am having the same issue. There is no error in laravel log and the Mail::failures() returning simply the mail ID to which we are sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

I've had troubles with using variables inside the mail::send .. and im also not sure if mail::send returns boolean or such... I've used something like what I wrote  down in the past.

```
   $nameSend = Input::get('name');
    Mail::send('Emails.email', $data, function($message) use ($nameSend){
        $message->from('webmaster@example.com', $nameSend);
        $message->to('amirhasan.hesam@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    });
```

.
.

```
if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {

  $output = "There was one or more failures. They were: \n";

  foreach(Mail::failures as $email_address) {
     $output = $output. $email_address ."\n";
  }
 return $output;
}
return "Success!";
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with input type! in fact `Mail::send` should send 1 if the send is successful or 0 if it is unsuccessful. in my case it returns 0 and for `Mail::failures()` with your code it returns : `There was one or more failures. They were: amirhasan.hesam@gmail.com` actually i really need to know why it fails!!

Comment: Have you checked the laravel log? sometimes email fail sending and its because of error connecting to the smtp

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use Mail facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```